# How can I configure NeoVim to use different language servers for different directories of the same project?

Tags: neovim, lsp, filetype-typescript

This is my folder structure:

- project

  - back (backend files written for deno)
  - front (frontend files where I use esbuild)
  - contract (interface files used both in back and in front)
  - deno.jsonc (for deno)
  - package.json (for esbuild)

How do I configure NeoVim so that it would use denols only in back and contract directory but will use tsserver in front?
It seams that setting a `root_dir` function is not enough since it checks which server it should run only once and then only checks if newly opened file has the same root_dir.

I tried also using symlinks for `contract` but unfortunately with this solution telescope does not worked properly.